# How to return join table objects associated with scoped has_many :through

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models: post, marking, tag. `marking` is a join table between `post` and `tag`. Post `has_many` markings and `has_many` tags through markings. I have certain "sticky" tags that I want to create a scope around. My object is to get markings between a particular post and its tags (tags that have the "sticky" scope). Is there a way to do that either with a join or in a way that's less verbose than this?

```
markings = post.tags.sticky.map { |t| Marking.where(post_id: post.id, tag_id: t.id }
```

The following query seems to be "looking" at the markings I want, but it will return tags not markings:

```
post.tags.sticky.joins(:markings)
```

What little I see in API dock for #joins looks like I'm limited to returning objects of the type that called #joins. Since I can't call #joins on a marking object I may be out of luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `markings` is used through the `tags` association, the `joins(:markings)` is not necessary. You may use the select statement :

```
post.tags.sticky.select('markings.id, markings.whatever_attribute')
```